# How can I convert this SQL to use Laravel Query builder?

Tags: laravel

This Is my SQL:

```
DELETE FROM valores_integracao_marketplace_fornecedor_user 
WHERE configuracao_marketplace_id (
        SELECT id FROM configuracoes_marketplace
         WHERE chave = 'something');
```

I have tried the following

```
DB::table('valores_integracao_marketplace_fornecedor_user')->whereExists(function($query){
    $query->select('configuracao_marketplace_id')
    ->from('valores_integracao_marketplace_fornecedor_user')
    ->where('chave', '=', 'something');
})->delete();
```

But this deletes the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

Youre subquery in SQL looks in the `configuracoes_marketplace` table, but the PHP version looks in `valores_integracao_marketplace_fornecedor_user`.